# How do I join two ORM tables in sqlalchemy, but get both columns back?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I've got some code that looks an awful lot like this:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()


class OneThing(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'one'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.Text)
    value = sa.Column(sa.Text)


class OtherThing(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'other'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    some_deal = sa.Column(sa.Text)
    other_deal = sa.Column(sa.Text)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

session = sa.orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
one = OneThing()
one.id = 42
one.name = 'hi'
one.value = 'roscivs'
session.add(one)
other = OtherThing()
other.id = 42
other.some_deal = 'brown'
other.other_deal = 'and sticky'
session.add(other)
session.commit()
```

Now, I can run the following:

```
for row in session.query(OneThing).outerjoin(OtherThing, OneThing.id == OtherThing.id):
    print(row)
```

And it will print a row. Obviously I don't have a `__repr__` so it's just going to print out the default repr that's pretty  ugly. But let's say I want the `other_deal` value, so I put in `print(row.other_deal)`.

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 43, in <module>
    print(row.other_deal)
AttributeError: 'OneThing' object has no attribute 'other_deal'
```

And indeed you can see that the emitted SQL isn't quite what I wanted:

```
SELECT one.id AS one_id, one.name AS one_name, one.value AS one_value
FROM one LEFT OUTER JOIN other ON one.id = other.id
```

It *is* doing the outer join... but it's only returning the columns from the `one` table. I want `one` **and** the `other`. How do I get that?

I've tried [`add_entity`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html?highlight=add_entity#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.add_entity), but that did not do what I wanted.

Any clues how I can get columns from *both* models? (note, I can't add a `ForeignKey` relationship between the two tables)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting with some other things first, we will get to answer your actual question.

**First**, `declarative_base` provides a keyword argument constructor, so instead of this:

```
one = OneThing()
one.id = 42
one.name = 'hi'
one.value = 'roscivs'
```

you can write:

```
one = OneThing(id=42, name='hi', value='roscivs')
```

**Second**: Assuming there is a database relationship between two tables, you can use the `relationship` definition to inform `sqlalchemy` about the relationship between the models. Here I assume there is a ForeignKey from `id` column to `id` column, and it is one-to-one relationship:

```
class OtherThing(Base):
    ...
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey(OneThing.id), primary_key=True)
    ...
    one_thing = sa.orm.relationship(OneThing, backref=sa.orm.backref('other_thing', uselist=False))
```

In this case you can write your current query as below, and `sqlalchemy` will figure out the join conditions:

```
query = session.query(OneThing).outerjoin(OtherThing)
```

**Finally**, let's have the related data in the result. There are multiple options, but starting from what you have you can query for `OneThing` (only) and then navigate the relationships as defined above:

```
query = session.query(OneThing).outerjoin(OtherThing)
for one in query:
    print(one)
    print(one.other_thing.other_deal)
```

Another option is to query for both models at the same time, but note that the resulting rows contains tuples of `(OneThing, OtherThing)`:

```
query = session.query(OneThing, OtherThing).outerjoin(OtherThing)
for one, oth in query:
    print(one)
    print(oth)
```

Yet another option is to query only a subset of columns:

```
query = session.query(OneThing.name, OtherThing.other_deal).outerjoin(OtherThing)
for row in query:
    print(row)
# ('hi', 'and sticky')
```

Comment: Ah - I was trying a non-kwarg constructor for my sample and it was unhappy, and I was tired/needed to leave so I didn't take the time to figure that out :P

Comment: The second option (`for one, other in session.query(OneThing, OtherThing)`) approach is *exactly* what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: If your actual relationship is not `one-to-one` but `one-to-many`, the answer is easy to adapt by removing `uselist=True`. The `one` part of the resulting query might, of course, be appearing multiple times.